# If ${s_n}$ is Cauchy, show ${t_n = |s_n-s_1|}$ is also a Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

A sequence is Cauchy if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a natural number N s.t. for all $m,n \ge N$ we have $|s_m - s_n| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given,...

I know I want to use some sort of telescoping for this proof, but I'm stuck.

Comment: '$abs(x_m−x_1)=abs((x_m − x_m+1)+(x_m + 1 − x_m + 2)+...(x_n−1 − x_n) - x_1) <= abs(x_m − x_m + 1) + abs(x_m + 1 − x_m + 2)+...abs(x_n−1 − x_n) - abs(x_1) < abs(x_m - x_n - x_1) <= t_n - abs(x_n) < x_n$'  does this do it? @LlutzL

Comment: I give up.... I can't get the formatting to work!

Answer (score 3):

Use some extended version of the triangle inequality
$$
\Bigl||a-b|-|c-d|\Bigr|\le|a-c|+|b-d|.
$$
If necessary, prove this first.

Comment: $abs(x_m−x_1)=abs((x_m − x_m+1)+(x_m + 1 − x_m + 2)+...(x_n−1 − x_n) - x_1) <= abs(x_m − x_m + 1) + abs(x_m + 1 − x_m + 2)+...abs(x_n−1 − x_n) - abs(x_1) < abs(x_m - x_n - x_1) <= t_n - abs(x_n) < x_n$  does this do it? @LlutzL

Comment: No, it is a direct proof, no telescoping necessary.